# Identity Server 4 PersistedGrant Not Saving Custom Claims

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm using Identity Server 4 with token based authorization. I haven't implemented profiles at this stage, but for now the Identity Server is working with my custom `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` and is correctly persisting the authorization grants in the `PersistedGrants` table in my db.

The problem is that the db is failing to also save the custom claims I am applying at this stage.

To create the grant, I am doing the following in my password validator:

```
public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
{
    ...
    // validate the user using the context, then generate custom claims
    var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim() }; // add claims here

    context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(user.Id.ToString(), "password", claims);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

but when the persisted claim is created in the db, the Data column only contains the default claims:

```
{
    "CreationTime": "2019-08-21T16:38:18Z",
    "Lifetime": 2592000,
    "AccessToken": {
        // audiences, issuer, creation time, etc...
        "Claims": [
            {
                "Type": "client_id",
                "Value": "myClient",
                "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
            }, {
                "Type": "scope",
                "Value": "myAPI",
                "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
            }, {
                "Type": "scope",
                "Value": "offline_access",
                "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
            }, {
                "Type": "sub",
                "Value": "16",
                "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
            }, {
                "Type": "auth_time",
                "Value": "1566405497",
                "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
            }, {
                "Type": "idp",
                "Value": "local",
                "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
            }, {
                "Type": "amr",
                "Value": "password",
                "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
            }, {
                "Type": "name",
                "Value": "email@domain.com",
                "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
            }
        ],
    },
}
```

I feel like the solution is overloading the grants class to be sure the data property is properly initialized, but am new to IDServer4 and don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing my own `IProfileService` and providing it as a transient resource in my ID4 startup. The `GetProfileDataAsync` function implemented by the interface allows you to add claims to the user profile that you want accessible as claims on the authorization side.

I still think claims added in the password validator should be passed without additional code. Requiring an additional profile service to add them twice seems redundant.